# Trying to make a BMI calculator in HTML but the Inperial units aren't working

Tags: html, web, calculator

I have tried to switch around my measurements but its still giving me wack answers. Was wondering if anything in my code was wrong. Im not sure why and i dont have any errors. All its doing is saying that the BMI is really high after the calculations.
Also this is my first stack overflow post so if i get something wrong, please tell me.

```
  <html>
       <head>
    <title>BMI Calculator</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      
        function computeBMI() {
            var height = Number(document.getElementById("height").value);
            var heightunits = document.getElementById("heightunits").value;
            var weight = Number(document.getElementById("weight").value);
            var weightunits = document.getElementById("weightunits").value;
    
    
            //Convert all units to metric
            if (heightunits == "inches") height /= 3.93700787;
            if (weightunits == "lb") weight /= 2.20462;
    
            //Perform calculation
    
            //        var BMI = weight /Math.pow(height, 2)*10000;
            var BMI = Math.round(weight / Math.pow(height, 2) * 10000);
    
            //Display result of calculation
            document.getElementById("output").innerText = Math.round(BMI * 100) / 100;
    
            var output = Math.round(BMI * 100) / 100
            if (output < 18.5)
                document.getElementById("comment").innerText = "Underweight";
            else if (output >= 18.5 && output <= 25)
                document.getElementById("comment").innerText = "Normal";
            else if (output >= 25 && output <= 30)
                document.getElementById("comment").innerText = "Obese";
            else if (output > 30)
                document.getElementById("comment").innerText = "Overweight";
            // document.getElementById("answer").value = output; 
        }
    </script>
    </head>
     <body>
    <h1>Body Mass Index Calculator</h1>
    <p>Enter your height: <input type="text" id="height"/>
        <select type="multiple" id="heightunits">
            <option value="metres" selected="selected">metres</option>
            <option value="inches">inches</option>
        </select>
         </p>
    <p>Enter your weight: <input type="text" id="weight"/>
        <select type="multiple" id="weightunits">
            <option value="kg" selected="selected">kilograms</option>
            <option value="lb">pounds</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="computeBMI" onclick="computeBMI();">
    <h1>Your BMI is: <span id="output">?</span></h1>
    
    <h2>This means you are: <span id="comment"> ?</span> </h2> 
     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Btw the meters part works perfectly, its just the imperial im having trouble with.

Comment: I think your conversion factor is off for height. height in inches = 39.37*height in meters, or height in inches = height in centimeters /2.54

Comment: I just tryed to switch it to 2.54 and i did it and it says my BMI is 655. (if you run the code with height 67 weight 108 thats what you will get)

Comment: what units are your input height in? 67 inches makes sense for an adult, 67 centimeters does not, that's 26.4 inches

Comment: I put in 67 inches and 108 pounds and somehow got 655BMI.
if i run this in a BMI calculator or make it metric, i get 17. (in both mine and the CDC's BMI calculator)

Comment: I cant seem to find one, can any of you? Also i have some buttons that are made to convert C-K but for some reason after i hit them, the website goes to another page. (it loads the info for that, but it makes you need to hit the back arrow to get back to the website)

Comment: 1 inc = 0,0254 m , so if user input his height is 10 inch and then his height in meter is 0,0254 * 10 = 0,2 m.. i think your conversion is wrong, both weight and height..

Comment: that worked! thanks!

Comment: Ok, nice to helped

Comment: Remember, the formula is (Weight in kilograms) / (height in meters * height in meters)